# Vue-socket.io install failing, cannot find 'package.tgz'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

I'm trying to install the dependencies for a project that uses `vue` and `vue-socket.io` using a standard `npm install` command, but the installation keeps failing because `vue-socket.io` is looking for a `package.tgz` file that I apparently don't have. I keep getting this error message:

```
       Error extracting /Users/macpro/.npm/vue-socket.io/2.1.0/package.tgz 
archive: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/macpro/.npm/vue-
socket.io/2.1.0/package.tgz'
```

I've tried to install the package by itself and I keep getting the same error. I've double-checked that I have the right dependencies and that I'm installing the correct versions.

Does anyone know why it keeps looking for this file? Or what it is I'm missing in my install? It seems from the documentation that I should be able to just use `npm i vue-socket.io`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd update NPM to the latest version. If it still keeps failing, I'd open an issue in their repo.

Comment: That did it. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `ENOENT ... vue-socket.io/.../package.tgz` error and `vue-socket.io` is a recurrent problem on old NPM versions.

**Solution:** Update your NPM version.

Considering it is a fresh install, if this doesn't work, I'd open an issue in their issue tracker. Could be a bug (though generally unlikely).